# issues with custom jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, plugins

I've been struggling with a custom jQuery plugin. The entire point of it is the following: you click the trigger, a toolbox comes up. In that specific toolbox you have one input field in which you paste and submit a Youtube or Vimeo URL. Based on that URL I'm changing the video that's currently on the page.

The issue I'm having is that when I click the trigger, I get not one, three toolboxes ( if I have 3 videos on the page and I click the first one ), two toolboxes ( if I have 3 videos on the page and I click the second one ), one if I click the last one ( same condition ) - I'm pretty sure you know where this is going.

Here's the code:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.videowidget = function() {
return this.each(function(){    
    // declare variables
    var parent = $(this);
    var thisPos = $(this).offset();

    var widgetHtml = jQuery('<div class="tool-video"><ul><li><a href="#tool-video1">Video</a></li></ul>' +
                    '<div id="tool-video1">' +
                            '<form id="tool-video-form" action="#" method="post">' +
                            '<label for="tool-video-url">Please enter the URL of your video ( only Youtube or Vimeo accepted )</label>' +
                            '<input type="text" id="tool-video-url" name="tool-video-url" value="" class="marginFive">' +
                            '<a href="#submitVideo" class="videowidget-submit btn btn-success">Submit</a>' +
                            '<div class="tool-video-error"></div>' +
                        '</form>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<a href="#close" class="closeImageBox">Close</a>' + 
                    '<a href="#drag" class="dragHandler" title="Drag me !!!">Draggable</a>' +
                    '</div>');

    // check if the containing div has the class 'w-video'
    if($(this).hasClass('w-video')) {
        $(this).append('<a href="#video" class="videoPlaceholder">Video placeholder</a>');
        $('.videoPlaceholder').bind('click', function() {

        // insert the video widget and apply the required settings ( positioning, drag, tabs )
        widgetHtml.appendTo('body').css(thisPos).fadeIn().draggable({handle: 'a.dragHandler', cursor: 'move'}).tabs();
        $('.videowidget-submit').click(function(){
            // value of the submitted url
            var url = $(this).prev('input').val();
            // regex to match provider
            var provider = url.match(/(?:http:\/\/)?(:?www.)?(\w*)/)[2], id;
            if(provider == "youtube") {
                id = url.match(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www.)?(\w*).com\/.*v=(\w*)/)[2];
                // remove the curent iframe and replace it with the one bellow using the ID of the submitted URL
                var youtubeTemplate = '<iframe width="460" height="259" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ id +'?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                parent.find('iframe').remove();
                parent.append(youtubeTemplate);
                $('.tool-video-error, .tool-video').fadeOut();
                return false;
            } else if (provider == "vimeo") {
                id = url.match(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www.)?(\w*).com\/(\d*)/)[2];
                // remove the curent iframe and replace it with the one bellow using the ID of the submitted URL
                var vimeoTemplate = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ id +'?wmode=opaque" width="460" height="259" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
                parent.find('iframe').remove();
                parent.append(vimeoTemplate);
                $('.tool-video-error, .tool-video').fadeOut();
                return false;
            } else if (provider == "youtu") {
                id = url.match(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www.)?(\w*).be\/*(\w*)/)[2];
                // remove the curent iframe and replace it with the one bellow using the ID of the submitted URL
                var youtubeTemplate = '<iframe width="460" height="259" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ id +'?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                parent.find('iframe').remove();
                parent.append(youtubeTemplate);
                $('.tool-video-error, .tool-video').fadeOut();
                return false;
            } else {
                // throw error if the submitted URL doesn't match youtube or vimeo
                $('.tool-video-error').html('Error: The URL you submitted doesn\'t appear to be valid ').fadeIn();
            }
                return false;
            });
            // close the toolbox
            $('.closeImageBox').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().fadeOut();
                return false;
            });
        return false;
        });
    } else {
            // do nothing
    }
});
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: could you put that into a jsfiddle maybe ? Did you bind the click event to a specific element or a class that is maybe contained by 3 different field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't provide a context for your selectors when you select by class to do the bindings.

```
$('.videowidget-submit').click(...)
```

So when you have several elements in the page onto you apply your plugin, it binds to all elements with class "videowidget-submit" instead of just the current instance.

Add a context to the followin selectors, like this (I may have forgotten some, check you code).

For the `<a>` link to open the popup:

```
$(this).find('.videoPlaceholder').bind('click', ...)
```

For the elements inside the popup:

```
widgetHtml.find('.videowidget-submit').click(...)

widgetHtml.find('.tool-video-error, .tool-video').fadeOut()

widgetHtml.find('.closeImageBox').click(...)
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/PSmc8/)**

Comment: Mate, you're a star! It's working. Point is I'm novice in jQuery plugin building, but with your answer I'm pretty sure I'm able to sort out my other issues!
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

From a very quick look at the code it seems that

```
$('.videoPlaceholder')
```

and

```
$('.videowidget-submit')
```

are not limited to the context of the $(this) object so they are registering the events on each of the instances on the page. im not sure if there are more locations where this is happening as well.

I have used the JqueryUI toolkit to write my own JQuery Plugins and its quite nice and easy to set up. A nice place to start with this is 
 http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget-factory